# why my angular app not working?

Tags: angularjs

i am using the new angularjs `v1.5.7` But I don't know what is wrong with my code, that my app is not running at all.

here is my html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html ng-app="myApp">
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Testing App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="main">
    <h1>Testing page {{2+2}} {{name}}</h1> //i am not getting any result
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

here is my app.js file :

```
angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp').controller('main', function ($scope) {

    alert('hi')

    $scope.name = "testing";
});
```

i am not getting either error or working output here. any one help me here? and correct me?

Comment: What does the console say?

Comment: you are putting ng-app in wrong place

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move the `ngApp` directive onto your `html` or `body` tag, it is currently on the `doctype` declaration.

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Testing App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="main">
    <h1>Testing page {{2+2}} {{name}}</h1> //i am not getting any result
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The directive needs to be on an element, which currently it is not.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.learn-angular.org/

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Testing App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="main">
    <h1>Testing page {{2+2}} {{name}}</h1> //i am not getting any result
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

You have to define the ng-app **not** in DOCTYPE!

`<html ng-app="myApp">` would be correct

Answer (score 1):

You can not assign ng-app to DOCTYPE . DOCTYPE is used only for telling the type of the doc and the bootstrapping of angular happens when it detect a ng-app directive on html tag .